# Xunit will not collaborate with Database to find content

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

My problem is that if I need to test any code for the database. - then Indicates the error that it is the null error.

But I just run the code in browser. Then I will basically be able to find email or no wrong email.

I have done two different tests. One of them works and must give true while the other must give false because they do not exist in the database.

When I run them through browser they give real values while when I run them through xunit test. so run it in no way.

**This is in project testing.**

```
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;

    public UserTest()
    {
        _accountService = new AccountService(null, null);
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("test@test.co")]
    [InlineData("test1@test.co")]
    public void CheckMailTrue(string mail)
    {
        var result = _accountService.FindEmail(mail);
        Assert.True(result);
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("te123123st@test.co")]
    [InlineData("aaaaJaeasdsper@test.co")]
    [InlineData("123Jesper@test.co")]
    public void CheckMailFalse(string mail)
    {
        var result = _accountService.FindEmail(mail);
        Assert.False(result);
    }
```

Web - Startup.cs. - This file is in the Web part,

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<dinekompetencer_dbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db"))
            );
    }
```

AccountService.cs - **This one is in the Service section.**

```
    private readonly dinekompetencer_dbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IPasswordService _passwordService;
    public AccountService(dinekompetencer_dbContext dbContext, IPasswordService passwordService)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _passwordService = passwordService;
    }

    public bool FindEmail(string mail)
    {
        var result = _dbContext.UserData.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Mail == mail);
        return result == null;
    }
```

What I would like to conclude is that my test does not show any kind of null reference exception problems.

**Error**

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is how the database is set up in my dinekompetencer_dbContext.cs file. located in the Data project.

```
   public dinekompetencer_dbContext(){}

    public dinekompetencer_dbContext(DbContextOptions<dinekompetencer_dbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<UserData> UserData { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserData>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Created).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.FullName).IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.Mail).IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.PasswordValue).IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.Salt).IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).IsRequired();
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
```

[image: Error for Test]

Comment: You can't use appsettings.json as Configuration in test project from Web project . If you want to use, you should make a custom implementation.

Comment: Okay, so that means that in a way I also have to have data in the test part or how should I handle it? or are there other ways I might have to do it? Maybe link it to how I can do it? @enisn Thanks for u comment